# In Ruby, what is the cleanest way of obtaining the index of the largest value in an array?

Tags: ruby, arrays, indexing, max

If `a` is the array, I want `a.index(a.max)`, but something more Ruby-like.  It should be obvious, but I'm having trouble finding the answer at so and elsewhere.  Obviously, I am new to Ruby.

Comment: I think you've got it. What's non-rubylike about that?

Comment: Ben, I was looking for something like a.max_index. Guess it's not built in.

Comment: Even if the function you want is not built in, you can still add a `.max_index` member to the `Array` class.  Here's an example of extending `String` or `Integer` with a custom member: http://www.hawkee.com/snippet/1260/

Answer (score 130, accepted):

For Ruby 1.8.7 or above:

```
a.each_with_index.max[1]
```

It does one iteration. Not entirely the most semantic thing ever, but if you find yourself doing this a lot, I would wrap it in an `index_of_max` method anyway.

Comment: Wow.  How does this do what it does?

Comment: Aaah, got it. each_with_index.max returns an array with the first element being the value and the second being the index of it. Very nice, Chuck.

Comment: Although actually still foggy as to why exactly it returns an array like this...heh.

Comment: Chuck, I was aware of this method, but thought Ruby would have a way of returning just the index.  (For any others new to Ruby, a.each_with_index.max returns the array [max value, index of max value], so Chuck is just pulling out the second element.)

Comment: `each_with_index` without a block returns an enumerator that gives the item and its index. We then send `max` to this enumerator, which does the standard `max` algorithm on item-index pairs. `Array.<=>` is implemented so that the first item determines the ordering (unless there's a tie, in which case the second is compared, and so on), so this works basically the same as doing `max` on an array of the values themselves. Then to get the index, we ask for the second item of the result (since we got a series of `[value, index]` pairs from `each_with_index`).

Comment: Boy, so is fast!  The five comments before mine were posted while I was composing my comment.

Comment: Nice. I was unaware that doing a max on a 2D array like this just compares the value of the first element in each array.

Comment: That's a great way of doing it.
If using Ruby 1.8.6, `require 'backports'` to get `#each_with_index`

Comment: And if you want the max of some function of the array elements, you can use `max_by` in the same way. For example `[0, 1,-1,2].each_with_index.max_by{|x,i| (-x) ** 3}[1]` will equal 2

Comment: @bergyman It doesn't compare just the first element. It starts comparison with the first element, but it will move on to subsequent elements if the first elements are equal. As such, if there are multiple maximum elements in the array, this solution will give the last one.

Comment: I was just drawn back to this question after many moons, and noticed that when the array `a` contains  multiple maximum values, `a.index(a.max)` will return the index of the first and `a.each_with_index.max[1]` will return the index of the last, so the choice of which to use may depend on the context.

Comment: The above fails is one of the elements is nil.

Comment: @Dave All Array iteration methods will fail on `nil`. Except the ones that deal with `nil`. So you need to get rid of `nil`s.

Answer (score 19):

In ruby 1.9.2 I can do this;

```
arr = [4, 23, 56, 7]
arr.rindex(arr.max)  #=> 2
```

Comment: This is basically a worse version of the unwanted original solution.

Answer (score 11):

Just wanted to note a behavioral and performance difference for some of the solutions here. The "tie breaking" behavior of **duplicate** max elements:

```
a = [3,1,2,3]
a.each_with_index.max[1]
# => 3
a.index(a.max)
# => 0
```

Out of curiosity I ran them both in `Benchmark.bm` (for the `a` above):

```
user     system      total        real
each_with_index.max  0.000000   0.000000   0.000000 (  0.000011)
index.max  0.000000   0.000000   0.000000 (  0.000003)
```

Then I generated a new `a` with `Array.new(10_000_000) { Random.rand }` and reran the test:

```
user     system      total        real
each_with_index.max
  2.790000   0.000000   2.790000 (  2.792399)
index.max  0.470000   0.000000   0.470000 (  0.467348)
```

This makes me think unless you specifically need to choose the higher index max, `a.index(a.max)` is the better choice.

Answer (score 10):

Here is what I am thinking to answer this question :

```
a = (1..12).to_a.shuffle
# => [8, 11, 9, 4, 10, 7, 3, 6, 5, 12, 1, 2]
a.each_index.max_by { |i| a[i] }
# => 9
```

Answer (score 3):

Here is a way to get all the index values of the max values if more than one.

Given:

```
> a
=> [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 9, 9, 2, 3]
```

You can find the index of all the max values (or any given value) by:

```
> a.each_with_index.select {|e, i| e==a.max}.map &:last
=> [7, 8]
```

Comment: You can use `each_with_object` plus `with_index` and skip the `map(&:last)`; `a.each_with_object([]).with_index { |(e, arr), i| arr << i if e == a.max }`.

Answer (score 2):

```
a = [1, 4 8]
a.inject(a[0]) {|max, item| item > max ? item : max }
```

At least it's Ruby-like :)

Comment: Dammit! I was cooking up a solution using inject - you beat me to it! ;)

Comment: Also - original question was to get the index, so this would have to be changed to:  
a.inject(0) {|index, num| num > a[index] ? a.find_index(num) : index}

Answer (score 1):

Using `#each_with_index` and `#each_with_object`. Only one pass required.

```
def index_of_first_max(e)
  e.each_with_index.each_with_object({:max => nil, :idx => nil}) { |x, m| 
    x, i = x

    if m[:max].nil? then m[:max] = x
    elsif m[:max] < x then m[:max] = x; m[:idx] = i
    end
  }[:idx]
end
```

Or combining `#each_with_index` with `#inject`:

```
def index_of_first_max(e)
  e.each_with_index.inject([nil, 0]) { |m, x|
    x, i = x
    m, mi = m

    if m.nil? || m < x then [x, i]
    else [m, mi]
    end
  }.last    
end
```