# How do I find the index of the maximum value of an array?

Tags: arrays, ruby, max, ruby-2.4

I tried the solution recommended here -- [In Ruby, what is the cleanest way of obtaining the index of the largest value in an array?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2149802/in-ruby-what-is-the-cleanest-way-of-obtaining-the-index-of-the-largest-value-in)

```
array = [nil, nil, nil, nil, nil, 0.9655172413793104, nil, nil]
idx = array.each_with_index.max[1]
```

But am getting some exceptions:

```
ArgumentError: comparison of Array with Array failed
    from (irb):4:in `each'
    from (irb):4:in `each_with_index'
    from (irb):4:in `each'
    from (irb):4:in `max'
    from (irb):4
    from /Users/davea/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0/gems/railties-5.0.3/lib/rails/commands/console.rb:65:in `start'
    from /Users/davea/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0/gems/railties-5.0.3/lib/rails/commands/console_helper.rb:9:in `start'
    from /Users/davea/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0/gems/railties-5.0.3/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:78:in `console'
    from /Users/davea/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0/gems/railties-5.0.3/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:49:in `run_command!'
    from /Users/davea/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0/gems/railties-5.0.3/lib/rails/commands.rb:18:in `<top (required)>'
    from bin/rails:4:in `require'
    from bin/rails:4:in `<main>'
```

Comment: How do you determine if `nil` is less than or greater than a float? Assuming you think `nil` is equivalent to zero, then you could squeeze `.map(&:to_f)` into the chain.

Comment: What should the result be if there are multiple maximum values?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you want to omit `nil`s from the result, then you can use:

```
array.index(array.compact.max)
```

Or if you wish to treat `nil`s like zeros, then first convert them to `Float`s:

```
array.index(array.map(&:to_f).max)
```

In the event of a tie, this will return the index of the **first** max value. You could also get the **last** index with `Array#rindex`.

Answer (score 0):

```
def max_idx(array)
  mx = array.select { |e| e.kind_of?(Numeric) }.max 
  mx ? array.each_index.select { |i| array[i] == mx } : nil
end      

require 'bigdecimal'
max_idx [nil,3,1]                   #=> [1]
max_idx [nil,3.2,"cat",1]           #=> [1]
max_idx [nil,3,nil,1,3]             #=> [1,4]
max_idx [nil,3.2,nil,1,3.2]         #=> [1,4]
max_idx [nil,Rational(3),1]         #=> [1]
max_idx [nil,BigDecimal.new("3"),1] #=> [1]
max_idx [nil,nil,nil]               #=> nil
```